# Unit tests for Microsoft Reporting Service

Tags: unit-testing, reporting-services

There is a simple way to create unit tests for Microsoft Reporting Service Reports? I am looking for some tools that help me do it.

Comment: This is very broad. SSRS reports can be accessed in many ways. Please describe the way you access your report.

Comment: I am not using SSRS reports. I am just considering using it embedded in a web application. But if I cannot create unit tests for the reports maybe is to risky using this type of service.